# Access 2013, Append query, automatically change primary keys before appending

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have two tables that need to have an append and update query run regularly.

`tbl1`: Updated by local users in real time

`tbl2`: Imported copy of `tbl1`, remote users download it, work off of it then update `tbl1` using the update and append queries below.

When users create new records in `tbl2` then run those queries, `Tbl1` records with matching primary keys (Built in auto-number) get overwritten. I have a solution in mind but would gladly entertain a better one.

I'd like the remote users' PK added to some value before updating. Is there something I can insert into the update query that will "add 1000000000 to PK" for a remote user? Then I'll just give each remote users some million series number(these numbers are invisible to users).

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 ( pk, thing1, thing2, thing3)
FROM tbl2 
LEFT JOIN tbl1 
ON tbl2.[pk] = tbl1.[pk];

UPDATE tbl2 
INNER JOIN tbl1 
ON tbl2.PK = tbl1.PK 
SET

tbl1.[thing1] = IIf([tbl2].[thing1] Is Null,[tbl1].[thing1],[tbl2].[thing1]), 

tbl1.[thing2] = IIf([tbl2].[thing2] Is Null,[tbl1].[thing2],[tbl2].[thing1]), 

tbl1.[thing3] = IIf([tbl2].[thing3] Is Null,[tbl1].[thing3],[tbl2].[thing3]);
```

**Edit 1:** For Newd

Currently I create three new lines of data here locally. PKs are 1, 2 and 3. A remote users does the same thing, PKs 1, 2 and 3. Then he updates `tbl1`. `tbl1` now has his rows 1, 2 and 3 but not mine.

What I would like to happen is this. After the update, `tbl1` has rows numbered 1, 2, 3, 1000000, 1000001 and 1000002.

So my numbering starts at 1. Remote user 1 has numbers starting at 1000000. Remote user 2 has numbers starting at 2000000.

I need a unique identifier for each record. In Excel, users have added 10000+ rows of data without any consistent unique way to identify a row. So I need something to use as a primary key.

Comment: Can you clarify: `I'd like the remote users' PK added to some value before updating`? Is there a risk that a record that `RemoteUser1` adds might also be added in by `RemoteUser2`?
Also I think on your 2nd `IIF` statement you mean `[tbl2].[thing2]` instead of` `[tbl2].[thing1]`.

Comment: What is the purpose to keeping the PK of your remote users?  Could you simply just leave it to autonumber as usual and add a field to say which remote user added the record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the following SQL will change the increment and seed number:

```
ALTER TABLE Table ALTER COLUMN Field COUNTER(1000000,1)
```

Where 1000000 is the new seed value and 1 the increment.